# execute delphi web service from browser

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap, delphi-2005

I've been working on a set of ISAPI web service DLLs in Delphi 2005 that interact with our server application but I'm having real difficulty debugging issues in the web services.

At this time, I have a test SOAP server application as a Web App Debugger executable which uses the same units as the real DLLs.

I can compile and run my SOAP EXE, run the Web App Debugger tool, start the ServerInfo server, and see my SOAP app in the list of Registered Servers.

If I select it from the list and click on Go, it shows the normal Service Info Page, where I can view interfaces and the WSDL.

What I now want to do is Execute one of the methods (a simple one that returns the version info of the ISAPI DLL), and view the request and response by looking at the Log tab of the Web App Debugger, however, I've not found a way to execute the method.

Do I really need to code a special client app to test my web methods? Most examples I've seen online just say to use `http://server/service/class/method?parameter=value` to execute a web service method, but that doesn't seem to work with a Delphi SOAP web service.

Comment: Instead of writing the client yourself, you can also use the (free) SoapUI utility. It also nicely shows request and response body.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the client to connect to the machine running the WebAppDebugger. (Typically localhost)

Run the WebAppDebugger and click on the Start button.  The 'default URL' lights up... by default is

```
http://localhost:8081/ServerInfo.ServerInfo
```

Then run your WAD server project within the IDE and put in your desired breakpoint somewhere in the server code.

If running your client on the same machine, change your client to use the local host address... if you connect today to:

```
http://www.yourhost.com/yourapp.dll/yourclass/yourmethod
```

change the client to connect to something like this for debugging the traffic:

```
http://localhost:8081/wadClassName/yourclass/yourmethod
```

The name of the Web Application Debugger class is defined when you create the WAD project.